# How to store in cache all of the data every run and check it next time on the next run if it already existing on the cache for faster runtime?

Tags: powershell, caching, stored-procedures, foreach, parallel-processing

Hello I am a Powershell beginner and self learner. I finally made my script faster by caching the last data from the last run.

Now I am trying to store everything when I am running my script. May I ask what would be the best way to store all the data from all runs and check it first before the next run if the data is already existing?
Thank you so much in advance guys

Here is my Code:

```
function Get-CachedGroupMembership($groupname){
        $groupName = "cached_$($groupName)"
        $cachedResults = Get-Variable -Scope Global -Name $groupName -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
        if($null -ne $cachedResults){
         "found cached result"
         $existing = write-host "Check: i found existing"
         return $cachedResults,  $existing
        }
        else{
         $searching = write-host "Check: Searching"
         $results = get-adgroup $groupname -properties memberof, members
         Set-CachedGroupMembership -groupName $groupName -value $results
         
         return $searching
        }
     }
    
     Function Set-CachedGroupMembership($groupName,$value){
        Set-Variable -Scope Global -Name $groupName -Value $value
        return $value
    }
      function Get-ADUsers_cached { 
        param ( 
            [Parameter(ValuefromPipeline = $true, mandatory = $true)][String] $GroupName
        ) 
        [int]$circular = $null
    
        # result holder
        $resultHolder = @()
            $table = $null 
            $nestedmembers = $null 
            $adgroupname = $null     
    
            # get members of the group and member of
            # $ADGroupname = get-adgroup $groupname -properties memberof, members
            $ADGroupname = Get-CachedGroupMembership -GroupName $groupName 
    
            # list all members as list (no headers) and save to var
            $memberof = $adgroupname | select -expand memberof 
           
            if ($adgroupname) {  
                if ($circular) { 
                    $nestedMembers = Get-ADGroupMember -Identity $GroupName -recursive 
                    $circular = $null 
                } 
                else { 
                    $nestedMembers = Get-ADGroupMember -Identity $GroupName | sort objectclass -Descending
                    # if get adgroupmember returns nothing, it uses the members for ordinary getADGroup
                    if (!($nestedmembers)) {
                        $unknown = $ADGroupname |select -expand members
                        if ($unknown) {
                            $nestedmembers = @()
                            foreach ($member in $unknown) {
                                $nestedmembers += get-adobject $member
                            }
                        }
                    }
                } 
                # loops through each member
                ForEach($nestedmember in $nestedmembers){ 
                    # creates the properties into a custom object. 
                    $Props = @{
                        Type            = $nestedmember.objectclass;
                        Name            = $nestedmember.name;
                        DisplayName     = "";
                        ParentGroup     = $ADgroupname.name;
                        Enabled         = "";
                        Nesting         = $nesting;
                        DN              = $nestedmember.distinguishedname;
                        Comment         = ""
                        EmployeeNumber  = "";
                        LastLogonDate   = "";
                        PasswordLastSet = "";
                    } 
                    # if member object is a user
                    if ($nestedmember.objectclass -eq "user") { 
                        # saves all the properties in the table. 
                        $nestedADMember = get-aduser $nestedmember.Name -properties enabled, displayname, EmployeeNumber, LastLogonDate, PasswordLastSet
                        $table = new-object psobject -property $props 
                        $table.enabled = $nestedadmember.enabled
                        $table.name = $nestedadmember.samaccountname
                        $table.displayname = $nestedadmember.displayname
                        $table.EmployeeNumber = $nestedadmember.EmployeeNumber
                        $table.LastLogonDate = $nestedadmember.LastLogonDate
                        $table.PasswordLastSet = $nestedadmember.PasswordLastSet
    
                        #save all in 1 storage
                        $resultHOlder += $table | select type, name, displayname, parentgroup, nesting, enabled, dn, comment , EmployeeNumber, LastLogonDate, PasswordLastSet
                    } 
    
    
                    # if member object is group
                    elseif ($nestedmember.objectclass -eq "group") {  
                        $table = new-object psobject -Property $props 
                        # if circular, meaning the groups member of list contains one of its members. 
                        # e.g. if group 2 is a member of group 1 and group 1 is a member of grou 2
                        if ($memberof -contains $nestedmember.distinguishedname) { 
                            $table.comment = "Circular membership" 
                            $circular = 1 
                        } 
                        # for circular output
                        #$table | select type, name, displayname, parentgroup, nesting, enabled, dn, comment 
                        #calling function itself
                        $resultHOlder += Get-ADUsers_cached -GroupName $nestedmember.distinguishedName                             
                    } 
                    else { 
                        if ($nestedmember) {
                            $table = new-object psobject -property $props
                            $resultHolder += $table | select type, name, displayname, parentgroup, nesting, enabled, dn, comment, EmployeeNumber, LastLogonDate, PasswordLastSet
                        }
                    } 
                } 
            } 
    
    
    
        return   $resultHOlder 
    
    }
    function Get-NestedGroupUsers_cached {
        param ( 
            [Parameter(Mandatory = $true)][String]$FileName,
            [Parameter(Mandatory = $true)][String]$searchFileURL
        )
        $storageHolder = @()
        $groupList = Get-Content $searchFileURL 
        $groupList |  ForEach-Object { 
            $allusers = Get-ADUsers_cached -GroupName $_
            $storageHolder += $allusers  
           
        }
        $storageHolder | select ParentGroup, Name, EmployeeNumber, Enabled, LastLogonDate, PasswordLastSet  |Export-Csv -Path "C:\Users\***\Desktop\$FileName.csv" -NoTypeInformation -Force
    }
```

Comment: "*store everything*" ... "*check it first before the next run*", you mean store the whole PowerShell session (even it is closed and restarted)? In that case what if the data is changed (e.g. someone is added to a group)? You will miss that as you reading the cache rather than the updated state of your groups...

Comment: Besides, I highly recommend you to avoid creating a new variable for each item in the cache but instead, use single [hashtable](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_hash_tables) to store all your items: `$Cache[$groupName] = ...`

Comment: Also consider that caching everything _indefinitely_ means freezing yourself in time - you will be operating on a _snapshot_ of what the directory looked like when you first discovered the accounts